# New-AzDnsRecordSet bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: azure, azure-dns

I am trying to create DNS records in a custom domain for a web app following [this tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/dns/dns-web-sites-custom-domain).

I come to the [step to Create the A Record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/dns/dns-web-sites-custom-domain#create-the-a-record). Now I run the following command in azure powershell

`New-AzDnsRecordSet -Name "@" -RecordType "A" -ZoneName "herewego.com" -ResourceGroupName "my-dns-zone-resource-group" -Ttl 600 -DnsRecords (New-AzDnsRecordConfig -IPv4Address "21.162.38.259")`

I get the following error message

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

What am I missing?

[image: Add Record to Azure DNS]

### Update

I used verbose flag, but its the same

```
vivekanand@Azure:~$ New-AzDnsRecordSet -Name "@" -RecordType "A" -ZoneName "herewego.com" -ResourceGroupName "my-dns-zone-resource-group" -Ttl 600 -DnsRecords (New-AzDnsRecordConfig -IPv4Address "21.162.38.259") --verbose

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('


vivekanand@Azure:~$ New-AzDnsRecordSet --verbose -Name "@" -RecordType "A" -ZoneName "herewego.com" -ResourceGroupName "my-dns-zone-resource-group" -Ttl 600 -DnsRecords (New-AzDnsRecordConfig -IPv4Address "21.162.38.259")

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('


This time, I use double quotes around (New-AzDnsRecordConfig -IPv4Address "21.162.38.259") as follow. I get a different error 

vivekanand@Azure:~$ New-AzDnsRecordSet -Name "@" -RecordType "A" -ZoneName "herewego.com" -ResourceGroupName "my-dns-zone-resource-group" -Ttl 600 -DnsRecords "(New-AzDnsRecordConfig -IPv4Address "21.162.38.259")"

bash: New-AzDnsRecordSet: command not found
```

Comment: Try to run the command with “—Verbose” switch. That should show you the exact request that’s being sent to Azure. HTH.

Comment: Its the same error, please see my update

Comment: Can you please try this: `New-AzDnsRecordSet -Name "@" -RecordType "A" -ZoneName "herewego.com" -ResourceGroupName "my-dns-zone-resource-group" -Ttl 600 -DnsRecords @(New-AzDnsRecordConfig -IPv4Address "21.162.38.259")`

Comment: I get command not found. Here it is.....    vivekanand@Azure:~$ New-AzDnsRecordSet -Name "@" -RecordType "A" -ZoneName "herewego.com" -ResourceGroupName "my-dns-zone-resource-group" -Ttl 600 -DnsRecords @(New-AzDnsRecordConfig -IPv4Address "21.162.38.259")
bash: New-AzDnsRecordSet: command not found

Comment: I believe the reason you are getting this error is because you chose `Bash` instead of `PowerShell`. Please choose `PowerShell` and then try the command. Bash is for using Azure CLI.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. That's the issue. Such silly of me

Answer (score 0):

As @Gaurav Mantri suggested, The command you are trying to use its an `Az-Powershell` module which definitely not work in `BASH` .

[image]

To create DNS record using `BASH` you can try with the [***az cli***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-getstarted-cli#create-a-dns-record)  `cmd`:

```
az network dns record-set a add-record -g MyResourceGroup -z xxxtest.com -n www -a xx.xx.xx.8
```

***OUTPUT***-
[image: ![enter image description here]
[image]

Still if you wish to use ***Az-powershell*** cmd select powershell from cloud shell .And can try with your command as mentioned in [***MS DOC***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/dns/dns-web-sites-custom-domain#create-the-a-record)

```
New-AzDnsRecordSet -Name "@" -RecordType "txt" -ZoneName "xxxxxx.com" `
 -ResourceGroupName "RG NAME" -Ttl 600 `
 -DnsRecords (New-AzDnsRecordConfig -IPv4Address "xx.xx.xx.8")
```

***OUTPUT:***
[image]